# How to pronounce 'et al' in presentation speech?

Tags: presentation

For giving a research presentation, I will need to refer to papers with multiple authors. When citing in the slides, I use the convention (as does everyone else) of 'et al.' How should I pronounce this when speaking during the presentation? I don't speak French fluently, but I know that the French pronunciation is 'ai-taal'. I am not sure how this would be pronounced in the English speaking world. What is the conventional pronunciation of 'et al.' in presentations for English speakers/researchers?

Comment: I've heard it pronounced to rhyme with "bet ball" or "bet pal".  I believe it's from Latin anyway, not French, so the French pronunciation isn't relevant.  You can also simply say "and others", "and coauthors", "and collaborators", etc.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_al.

Comment: In the U.S., the "bet pal" rhyming pattern sounds more correct to me. But for spoken language I'd probably go with "and coauthors". For a highly informal talk in front of a young, hip audience, you might consider other possibilities like "and the other dudes" (at least in case all coauthors are male).

Comment: If you're going to speak Latin, at least use the correct Latin words: _et alii/aliorum/alios/aliis_, depending on case; or _et aliae/aliarum/alias/aliis_, respectively, if all the others are female; or _et alia/aliorum/aliis/alia/alii_, respectively, if all the others are robots.  If you don't know which of those Latin words is correct, stick with "and coauthors".

Comment: Also, it is not from French but from Latin: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_al.#Etymology_1

Comment: @JeffE Good of you to include robots, in case I ever need to give a talk about a SciGenned paper. But, given that people often say "e.g." ("ee-gee"), there's a precedent for pronouncing unexpanded abbreviated Latin and I don't see why that can't be applied to "et al."

Comment: @DanRomik: One needs to add that "pal" is pronounced like "al (Bundy)", at least for Germans this is relevant, as the pronounciation as "carl" (silent r) is more common (PayPal adds to this by pronouncing it "PayParl" in commercials).

Comment: @phresnel speaking of pals and als, [this](https://youtu.be/ULjCSK0oOlI) would be another nice way to explain the pronunciation.

Comment: consider writing "First Author et al." but saying something like "From the group/lab of Jack McFamousperson" which might give valuable perspective on the cited work (for an audience familiar with the field)

Comment: @DavidRicherby (shudder) Ugh.  Just say "for example" (and "that is", "and so on", and so on).  I don't even let my students _write_ "e.g.", "i.e.", or "etc."

Comment: @JeffE those abbreviations are correct English, may I ask why don't you let your students write them? And what do you expect them to write instead of etc.? (And what about "ugh", are they allowed to write that?)

Comment: @DanRomik 'and so on'.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: ".But, given that people often say "e.g." ("ee-gee"), there's a precedent for pronouncing unexpanded abbreviated Latin" - that precedent is a bit of a special case because *e.g.* can be retconned into abbreviating English words, unlike (?) *et al.*, as far as I am aware. And even if you reject that retcon, a case can be made that pronouncing single letters like in English is different from pronouncing whole or partial words from another language like in English.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In standard usage, "e.g." doesn't abbreviate English words, so any argument based on the premise that it does or can is, at best, tenuous. And what about "i.e." and "N.B."?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The standard English pronunciation can be found in a dictionary, see, e.g., [*et al*. at MacMillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/et-al).

However, during a presentation, instead of reading that abbreviation, it is probably nicer to say something like: "Smith and his/her group/coauthors/colleagues published the paper [...]".

Comment: I tend to prefer "and coworkers", rolls off the tongue better. The usage "and his/her group" should be used with some care, as often the usage denotes that Smith is the PI, which may not be the case. (Indeed, in many fields the PI goes last, so a collaboration that publishes under Smith et al. is unlikely to be referred to as "the Smith group" in such fields.) I know you know - just some pitfalls for the OP & future visitors to be aware of.

Comment: +1 People read "i.e." as "that is" and "e.g." as "for example" (instead of reading out the letters or saying "id est" or "exempli gratia"), and I don't think "et al." should be treated any differently.

Comment: That MacMillan is a British pronunciation.  If the rest of your presentation is given with a British accent, go ahead and use it.

Comment: I find this quite inappropriate. In many disciplines the authors are ordered alphabetically. By speculating that it is "Smith and their group" you imply that Smith is the main author, which is sometimes factually incorrect.

Comment: @Dilworth In fact, I gave different options (coauthors, colleagues etc.) exactly for that reason: "Smith and his/her coauthors/colleagues/coworkers" does not imply any main author, and if the audience is composed of mathematicians they can certainly understand it the right way. If you have a better suggestion, please post it.

Comment: My suggestion is "Smith and all". Saying "and co-authors\colleagues" still insinuates a slight impression that Smith is the "main" author.

Answer (score 12):

I often just say "and others", "and friends", or just "Foo" for "Foo, et al.". People can see on the screen that there are others and refer to your references to see who those others are. No one is misled or confused if you drop the others in what you say aloud.

Comment: Not at all tongue-in-cheek, but this Foo chap gets a *lot* of papers out -- has anyone ever considered a special recognition award? ;)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz The award usually goes to Ibid.

Comment: There's always someone better :)

Comment: @MiloPrice I dunno. That guy Al does write a lot of papers. Always as second author, too, which is kinda weird.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Indeed. Ibid has an infinite average citation count and perhaps a higher overall impact than al, having written *no papers at all* but is massively cited. But they're both right up there.

Comment: So I guess Foo can't meet that high Bar.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, if there aren't that many authors, is simply to **say all names out loud when presenting**. In my field, where papers with more than 5 or so authors are uncommon, sometimes we would use "et al." to avoid having to fit more than one or two names on the slide, but the simplest is to say all names out loud when presenting. (And afterwards you can just say "they".)

Of course, this requires sufficient familiarity with the work to know off the top of your head the name of all these authors.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "et al." is that, unlike "etc.," it changes depending on the gender of the other authors, which is not always easily apparent. There are actually three different forms (masculine, feminine, and gender neutral) meaning "and others" and an additional completely separate phrase also abbreviated "et al." that means "and elsewhere." One would argue you could just say the gender-neutral "et alia," but that is usually only supposed to refer to things without gender, not things with an unknown gender. Because of these complications and, as is often the case, an ignorance of the gender of the other people involved in the report, I would just pronounce it, "ett ahl."

Comment: I don't get it: *al.* is a shortening, be it of *aliī*, *aliae* or even a single person (although that would be silly).